# How to algebraically solve for $e^s$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$p(1-p-a)e^{s(1-p-a)} = (1-p)(p+a)e^{-s(p+a)}$

Solving for $e^s = \frac{(1-p)(p+a)}{p(1-p-a)}$

Assume $a,p$ are constants in Reals and $s$ is a variable.

However I am not able to arrive to this answer.

Could somebody please explain how this is happening?

Comment: First multiply both sides by $e^{s(p+a)}$.

Comment: Use: $e^{x}e^y = e^{x+y}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said above.. multiply by $e^{p+a}$

then you have p(1-p-a)$e^{\delta}$=(1-p)(p+a)$e^{0}$.. (and from indices laws $e^{0}$ = 1)

dividing across by p(1-p-a) gives the wanted result.